# Integral by the definition solving, like derivative

Tags: integration

I think, this question, probably was asked many times, but I'm trying to understand this moment.

We have a function $f$ and to find the derivative, we have a lot of rules, etc, but we have a strict definition - $f'(x)=\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$. It's pretty simple and clear, it shows that $f'(x)$ just equals the stuff in the right side, and you can choose, which way is better for you - solve by rules, schemes, or solve by definition.

When we deals with integral, here goes different types, kinds of it: indefinite, definite, surface etc. For each of them there are rules, algorithms how to solve them. But is there a way to solve integral as in derivative case?

Comment: I'm confused by the question. Integrals have an analogous limit-sum definition.

Comment: I think you might want to look up Darboux sums, that should give you a similar idea to what you need.

Comment: Are you asking for a basic formulaic definition for integrals like a derivative?

Comment: @AlexR., can you explain in detail, I will be grateful

Comment: @FrankW., I seen limit-sum definition, but I, for some reason, thought it wasn't what I was looking for. But I didn't understood moment with division of a line, and if the integral is indefinite, what I need to do - to divide infinitely many segments?

Comment: @ArturKlochko as I said, google Darboux sums, it's quite descriptive really. It gives you the exact algebraic definition and nice images to motivate one to research integrals :)

Comment: I tend to think of the indefinite integral as a case where the bounderies are not known.  $F(x) = \int f(x) dx = \int_{a}^x f(y)dy + C$ where the "plus a constant" depends upon the value of $a$.  So $\int f(x) dx = C + \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_k \frac {f(a + k\frac {x-a}n)}{n}$.

Comment: @DBoss, thank you

Comment: @fleablood,what is a, k, z, n in the secod statement, and where x has gone?

Comment: @ArturKlochko Ok, so you know the definition of derivative in term of limit. For indefinite integral and definite integral, they also have definitions. Indefinite integral is defined to be the family of [antiderivaties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative) of the function (if exists), and definite integral is defined to be the limit of the [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) (if exists). [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus) connects the indefinite integral to the definite integral.

Comment: @AlexVong, yeah I know, that the Integration is 
inverse action with to differentiation. But I don't understand some thing, for example, if the solve of indefinite integral is the infinite primitives, how can we be sure that, when we getting the definite integral we will find only one of primitives? What if we will integrate in (-100000;1000000) range?

Comment: $a$ can be any real "starting point" (if possible it's best if it by $0$), $n$ is a natural number and $n\to \infty$.  $k$ is the index of the sum $\sum_{k=1}^n$.  And is right there?  It's the upper limit of the integral.

Comment: @fleablood, understood all, except where is the *x* -_- . int f(x) dx = C + \lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_k \frac {f(a + k\frac {x-a}n)}{n}(well, you understood) there is no x

Comment: @ArturKlochko Do you mean that since there are infinitely many antiderivatives, how can we know which one to pick for computing the definite integral?

Comment: @AlexVong, no. I understanding this like this: we have a *y=2x+3* function, the derivative will be 2, and derivative of *y=2x+4* and etc. When we finding antiderivative, solving the indefinite integral, we getting *2x+C*, it is *2x+1 ; 2x+2 ; 2x+3...* right? Now we ate solving definite integral, on the range from 0 to 10. We find a single integer. Why if there are *2x+1 ; 2x+2 ; 2x+3...*? Or I understand something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's talk about the definite and the indefinite integral.

Another name for the indefinite integral is the "anti-derivative".  This name makes much more sense to me; it's clear what we're looking for.  If we  want the anti-derivative of $f$, then we're looking for a function $F$ such that $F'=f$.  We have a special symbol for $F$.  Here it is:
$$F(x) = \int f(x) \, dx$$.
This squiggly line (that we call the integral sign) is just a special symbol that helps us remember which function we're finding the anti-derivate of.

Now, how about the definite integral?  This is a different beast entirely.  The definition of the definite integral (for functions that map the real numbers to the real numbers) is as follows:
$$\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{i=1}^N f(x_i) \Delta x_i.$$

That is, we're taking the interval [a,b] and dividing up into $N$ pieces, and then summing $N$ values of the function evaluated somewhere in each piece times the width of each piece.  And then we take the limit of those sums as the number of pieces goes to infinity.

Comment: Well, we were solving a area under the line, in the specific range, in one of the lessons, using programming, without using the integrals, and I understood it well. We just built the rectangles, that didn't were higher then line, finding there area, and sum it. 
The smaller the length of rectangle - the higher accuracy. I'm understanding, that this is something the same. Width is going to infinity - max accurancy, we sum something,  but I don't understand how we checks that we do not higher than curve, for example?

Comment: @ArturKlochko  It works even if the rectangle goes higher than the curve.  Give it a shot!  Rather than trying a specific point in each rectangle, try an arbitrary point.  Make the rectangles smaller, and see what happens.  You should find that you get closer and closer to the correct answer.

Comment: Ok, but I can't solve indefinite integral, by this way, yes?

Comment: No; indefinite integral (by definition) is an analytic expression.  When you're looking for an anti-derivative (a.k.a. indefinite integral) then you're looking for a function that you can differentiate (analytically) to get back your original function.

Comment: Ok, Understood.